# Checked=True on textbox textchange event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('.LblQTY').live('blur', function () {
    var rwtr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
    rwtr.find('.LblAmount').text(parseFloat(parseFloat(rwtr.find('.LblRate').text()) * parseFloat($(this).attr('value') == '' ? '0' : $(this).attr('value'))).toFixed(0).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
    var LblAmount = $(this).find('[id$="Grdlist"]');
    var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridViewProducts.ClientID %>");
    for (i = 0; i <= grid.rows.length; i++) {
        if (LblAmount.val() != 0) {    
            $('[id$="ChkTaskSelect"]').attr('checked', true);   
        }
    }
});
```

in this i am trying to do is when text changes of particular row i want checked=true of check box

Comment: Please don't use `.live()`. It was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, removed entirely in 1.9. Switch to `.on()`.

Comment: can you share the generated html sample as well

Comment: @Igle: No, jQuery objects don't have a `checked` property.

Comment: $('.LblQTY').live('blur',function(){ 

         var rwtr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
         rwtr.find('.LblAmount').text(parseFloat(parseFloat(rwtr.find('.LblRate').text())*parseFloat($(this).attr('value')==''?'0':$(this).attr('value'))).toFixed(0).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
    
       
         
         var tr = $(rwtr).parent().parent().parent(); //get the parent tr of the checkbox.
         var txtamount = $("td input[type=checkbox]", tr).get(0);
         txtamount.checked = true;         
     
    });

this is the solution

thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.prop()` to change the dynamic state of a checkbox:

```
$('[id$="ChkTaskSelect"]').prop('checked', true);
```

The attribute is used for the initial, default state, not the current state.

[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: i am geting this error"Object doesn't support this property or method".but i want only particular checkbox of that row in which text is chenging

Comment: You need to use a more specific selector, that references the element in a particular row. Since you haven't posted your HTML, we can't tell what it should be.